# How do I crash my phonegap app deliberately?

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to add a feature of restarting from crash for my applications. So, I need to simulate the crash abort. It should be easy but I just can't make it crash itself.

It's a phonegap application, and the best would be crashed from the javascript in html. But no matter I tried, the application does not crash, the application is just hang there and not responding any clicks. I've tried to write some codes in the java phonegap plugins, however, I can't make it crash as well. Any suggestion?

Comment: Cannot you just kill the process via the debugger?

Comment: Yes, I can. But this is not a real crash.

Comment: i preferably wouldn't like my app to crash

Comment: I've tried all that I can think of, including divide by zero, however, none of them work. I believe this is due to the error catch by phonegap wrapper. How can I bypass it?

Comment: This seems to work. Use window.location = "not_exist.html"; Then the phonegap app will get error and force quit after an alert box.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Object obj=null;
obj.toString();
```

This should cause a NullPointerException. When you don't catch it anywhere you should be able to test your recovery functionality. But think about a possibility to get bugreports from your users - elsewhere you will never be able to fix ugly bugs that happen only on other peoples devices.

Comment: Thanks, however, this doesn't work as well. This should work in a normal android app, however, since mine is phonegap app and seems like all these errors catch already.

Comment: Then you should ask this question in an PhoneGap webboard, here nobody will be able to answer it without knowing the code of PhoneGap. Beside of that I still think it is not a good idea to catch such crashes and to restart the app without notification - so you never are informed about bugs in your software.